# DB-Sync insanely slow

Tags: cardano-db-sync

So i built the latest node and db-sync releases from source. My node works great it was fully synced fairly quickly. the db-sync got to around %78 and then started going insanely slow. I still have about 400GB free, only using about 30/48GB of memory.

This is

```
ubuntu 22 with 
db sync 13.1.1.3
node 8.7.2
ghc 8.10
```

It updates about .01% everyday. So its just barely faster then the new transactions on the node each day. I have little script that compares the latest slot number between the node and the database. At this rate it wouldn't be updated for over 3 years

I don't have any errors I can find. the hard drive space and memory don't seem to be leaking. Any thoughts as to what the problem might be or how it can be optimized?

Comment: Is you disk storage for the database directly attached or network attached. Network attached storage is specifically advised against https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync#system-requirements

Comment: yeah, its a local hoard drive, everything is on the same OS/hardrive, including the postgres server. It updated quick until about 75%, then just slowed down.

Comment: Does your machine meet the system requirements in the document above? Are you on an SSD drive rather than an electro-mechanical one? Is this dedicated hardware or something like an AMazon AWS system? Please provide comprehensive info about your setup.

Comment: Its my home server. Its just a virtual box image. where I allocated 48 GB of memory and about 900 GB on a SSD that is supposed to be around 300+MB/S. Its not an M2 SSD but a SATA SSD. I allocated 4 cores of my 8 core processor.

Comment: I should note the Drive symbol is always 100% lit, even though its not really filling up any more space. Even if it were magnetic, It would be filling the space 100x faster then it currently is

Comment: Your system seems very similar to mine. MIne is a KVM virtual machine writing to a SATA SSD drive. One thing I do know about SSDs is that writes seem to slow down as the number of write cycles increases (I killed an SSD during the development of `db-sync`). If yours a new or an old SSD? You still have not shared details of the host machine that the VM runs on (`dstat` maybe?)). This seems like a system performance issue rather than a `db-sync` issue.

Comment: That's fair. My host machine has 64 gb of ddr4 memory, 8core ryzen 9 processor, and about 5 different hard drives. IMO this is a dbsync problem. It should be faster then this on a magnetic drive. I should say, just to experiment I moved the VM to a different hard drive with no changed results. IMO DB sync is just doing stuff way to inefficiently. I have decided to move to Kupo